# ASP.NET Core 6 Submit Button doesn't work

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

```
@model Category

<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Create Category</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="DisplayOrder"></label>
            <input asp-for="DisplayOrder" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Create</button>
        <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">
            Back to List
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

The code should add whatever is given from name and DisplayOrder to the database but it doesn’t do anything

Answer (score -1):

In your code example the `<form>` tag seem to not contain any information about which controller method to call when clicking the submit button.
If this is your problem, then you need to change your `<form>` tag to the following:

```
<form method="post" action="{Category}/{create}">
```

You will also need to make sure, that your controller method accepts a class which represents your form data.
Assuming that it is your model "Category", your controller method shoud accept an instance of this class:

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{

  [HttpPost]
  [Route("create")]
  public ActionResult Create(Category value)
  {
    // Do something
  }
}
```